# spring boot + thymeleaf JPAなしデータベースなしでページング機能を実装したいです

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

こんにちはJAVAの初心者です。
今はspring bootの勉強をしています。

以下のデータを使ってthymeleafで簡単なページング機能を実装したいです。
インターネット上はJPAを用いてページング機能を実装する例が多くあるますが、
今回はJPAとDB使っていませんので、どのように簡単なページング機能を実装できますでしょうか？
ご教示お願い致します。

spring boot version = 2.0.4
thymeleaf version = 3.0.2
java version = Java8

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/find", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String find(AttendanceListForm form, Model model) {

    AttendanceListDetail detail1 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail1.setListChkBox("");
    detail1.setOffice("1");
    detail1.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail1.setEmpNums("3");
    detail1.setEmpName("4");
    detail1.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail1.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail1.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail1.setOperationTime("8");
    detail1.setOverTime("9");
    detail1.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail1.setMoveTime("11");
    detail1.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail1.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail2 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail2.setListChkBox("");
    detail2.setOffice("1");
    detail2.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail2.setEmpNums("3");
    detail2.setEmpName("4");
    detail2.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail2.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail2.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail2.setOperationTime("8");
    detail2.setOverTime("9");
    detail2.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail2.setMoveTime("11");
    detail2.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail2.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail3 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail3.setListChkBox("");
    detail3.setOffice("1");
    detail3.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail3.setEmpNums("3");
    detail3.setEmpName("4");
    detail3.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail3.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail3.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail3.setOperationTime("8");
    detail3.setOverTime("9");
    detail3.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail3.setMoveTime("11");
    detail3.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail3.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail4 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail4.setListChkBox("");
    detail4.setOffice("1");
    detail4.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail4.setEmpNums("3");
    detail4.setEmpName("4");
    detail4.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail4.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail4.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail4.setOperationTime("8");
    detail4.setOverTime("9");
    detail4.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail4.setMoveTime("11");
    detail4.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail4.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail5 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail5.setListChkBox("");
    detail5.setOffice("1");
    detail5.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail5.setEmpNums("3");
    detail5.setEmpName("4");
    detail5.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail5.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail5.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail5.setOperationTime("8");
    detail5.setOverTime("9");
    detail5.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail5.setMoveTime("11");
    detail5.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail5.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail6 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail6.setListChkBox("");
    detail6.setOffice("1");
    detail6.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail6.setEmpNums("3");
    detail6.setEmpName("4");
    detail6.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail6.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail6.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail6.setOperationTime("8");
    detail6.setOverTime("9");
    detail6.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail6.setMoveTime("11");
    detail6.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail6.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail7 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail7.setListChkBox("");
    detail7.setOffice("1");
    detail7.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail7.setEmpNums("3");
    detail7.setEmpName("4");
    detail7.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail7.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail7.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail7.setOperationTime("8");
    detail7.setOverTime("9");
    detail7.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail7.setMoveTime("11");
    detail7.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail7.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail8 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail8.setListChkBox("");
    detail8.setOffice("1");
    detail8.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail8.setEmpNums("3");
    detail8.setEmpName("4");
    detail8.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail8.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail8.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail8.setOperationTime("8");
    detail8.setOverTime("9");
    detail8.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail8.setMoveTime("11");
    detail8.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail8.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail9 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail9.setListChkBox("");
    detail9.setOffice("1");
    detail9.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail9.setEmpNums("3");
    detail9.setEmpName("4");
    detail9.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail9.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail9.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail9.setOperationTime("8");
    detail9.setOverTime("9");
    detail9.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail9.setMoveTime("11");
    detail9.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail9.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail10 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail10.setListChkBox("");
    detail10.setOffice("1");
    detail10.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail10.setEmpNums("3");
    detail10.setEmpName("4");
    detail10.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail10.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail10.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail10.setOperationTime("8");
    detail10.setOverTime("9");
    detail10.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail10.setMoveTime("11");
    detail10.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail10.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail11 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail11.setListChkBox("");
    detail11.setOffice("1");
    detail11.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail11.setEmpNums("3");
    detail11.setEmpName("4");
    detail11.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail11.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail11.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail11.setOperationTime("8");
    detail11.setOverTime("9");
    detail11.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail11.setMoveTime("11");
    detail11.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail11.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail12 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail12.setListChkBox("");
    detail12.setOffice("1");
    detail12.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail12.setEmpNums("3");
    detail12.setEmpName("4");
    detail12.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail12.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail12.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail12.setOperationTime("8");
    detail12.setOverTime("9");
    detail12.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail12.setMoveTime("11");
    detail12.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail12.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail13 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail13.setListChkBox("");
    detail13.setOffice("1");
    detail13.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail13.setEmpNums("3");
    detail13.setEmpName("4");
    detail13.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail13.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail13.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail13.setOperationTime("8");
    detail13.setOverTime("9");
    detail13.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail13.setMoveTime("11");
    detail13.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail13.setState("13");

    AttendanceListDetail detail14 = new AttendanceListDetail();
    detail14.setListChkBox("");
    detail14.setOffice("1");
    detail14.setAPayStructure("2");
    detail14.setEmpNums("3");
    detail14.setEmpName("4");
    detail14.setAttendanceSheetRosterDays("5");
    detail14.setAPaidVacations("6");
    detail14.setCongratulationOrCondolenceLeave("7");
    detail14.setOperationTime("8");
    detail14.setOverTime("9");
    detail14.setHolidayWorkTime("10");
    detail14.setMoveTime("11");
    detail14.setTotalWorkingTime("12");
    detail14.setState("13");

    List<AttendanceListDetail> detailList = new ArrayList<>();
    detailList.add(detail1);
    detailList.add(detail2);
    detailList.add(detail3);
    detailList.add(detail4);
    detailList.add(detail5);
    detailList.add(detail6);
    detailList.add(detail7);
    detailList.add(detail8);
    detailList.add(detail9);
    detailList.add(detail10);
    detailList.add(detail11);
    detailList.add(detail12);
    detailList.add(detail13);
    detailList.add(detail14);

    form.setAttendanceListDetail(detailList);

    model.addAttribute("areaListItems", areaListItems());
    model.addAttribute("salesOffice", salesOffice());
    model.addAttribute("listDisplayer", listDisplayer());
    model.addAttribute("attendanceListForm", form);

    return "views/attendance/attendanceList";
}
```

thymeleaf

```
                <div class="container-fluid" id="pager">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 text-left">
                                <label class="control-label">1～30 / 100</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <div class="btn-group pull-left">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">1</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">2</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">3</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">4</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">5</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

英語ですが、[このページ](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-pagination)が参考になると思います。GitHubにソースコードも公開されています。

もしくは、[このページ](https://qiita.com/KevinFQ/items/ca68a3001bae19f92879)のJPAのリポジトリクラス（`WordRepository`）を使用する箇所を、JPAのリポジトリクラスを使用しないように変更すればいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました！